# Doctrine - Retrieving list of fields in subclass gets all fields in aggregate

Tags: php, doctrine

I have an object model that contains a class with several subclasses. 
The subclasses share a few fields from the parent, but they each have 
their own fields as well.

I'm using the column_aggregation inheritance type to do this because I 
want to be able to polymorphically store objects of the parent class 
type, but retrieve objects of the subclass types.

So far, I can retrieve the objects with their subclass types intact. 
My problem is that when I call getColumns() on any of the subclass , I 
get all the fields for the aggregated table, so I see every field from 
all the subclasses together.

Is there a way to only get the fields that actually belong the 
subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design-wise the output of `getColumns()` is correct (it merely returns all columns of the aggregated table). I think `Doctrine_Table->getColumns()` is oblivious to the fact that the table in question has sub-classes. Try to use `Doctrine_Table->getColumnDefinition()` or as a last resort `Doctrine_Table->getColumnOwner($column)` to infer which columns belong to which sub class.

Comment: Thanks...I ended up using a different approach to my entity model but this is good to know for the future.

Comment: ... and it's good to know that it's wrong! There is no way to retrieve that information (except analysing schema.yml). Just look at your Base(...) model and table classes. The parent table defines _all_ columns.